# Removing Derailleur Hanger from Devinci Spartan

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-hanger

So I'm in need of new derailleur hanger and bolt kit. My question is how to remove the hanger from my kinda frame (2018 Devinci Spartan). I'm used to just using a 5mm Allen key to unscrew two little screws on the backend but that's not the case for this one. I'm guessing the bolt there on the front where the quick release goes thru needs to be taken off before I can get to the hanger (based off the picture I provided). Tools to use? (socket wrench?) Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: FYI the hanger and bolt don't come as a kit. Try contacting Devinci for a replacement hanger, also there are a few aftermarket replacement hanger vendors. The bolt should be available as a spare part for the derailleur.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome back. Sweet ride and I hope to read more about Devinci and their bikes. Leading a sheltered life and really have only heard of the bikes in passing. In the interest of an answer for you, a Google search of "2018 c Spartan," lead me to the company's website and then to the  [Technical Manual](http://www.devinci.com/site_media/uploads/bikes/pdf/9702_-_Spartan_27.5_Carbon-RevB.PDF).

[image: excerpt from the manual]

As you can see on page 1 at the rear axle schematic, you will indeed remove that nut to release the split pivot derailleur hangar. They term the rear axle assembly, "Pivot Kit Shaft," and the right side has about 5 pieces, counting the bolt, bearing, axle and dropout insert. The hangar is the other piece. Included in the document are torque values for every connection. These should be closely adhered to along with good threaded fastener techniques (greasing threads, Loctite where indicated, clean surfaces, etc). This is especially so for carbon frames. The schematic helps immensely, making more words superfluous.  Good riding!

Answer (score 0):

Addressing what tool to use. Use the box/ring end of a decent quality wrench to get the bolt off. Don't use an adjustable wrench, these are prone to slip on tight bolts and will mar the bolt head flats.

A torque wrench is necessary to tighten the bolt to the correct torque setting. These are expensive. You can assemble yourself then ask a local bike store to apply the correct torque. They may charge you a small fee or do it for free if you buy some small items at the same time.

Comment: (to the OP) Torque wrenches are expensive, but well worth it if you're doing any work on a mountain bike, where, IMO, e.g., the torque on the stem's faceplate bolts are even more important than on a road bike.